# AWS cfn resource creation failed for recordset

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I wanted to deploy a static website using cloudformation but I am having issues creating the record set. The stack creation was successful until the hosted zone in resource section. I'm not sure why there is an issue creating the record set for a hosted zone.

> Error: The following resource(s) failed to create: [RecordSet].

```
        ---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion:  '2010-09-09'
Description: 'Assuming that you already have a Hosted Zone registered with Amazon Route 53, this Cfn template is to create a static site'
# Metadata:
#   'AWS::CloudFormation::Interface':
#     ParameterGroups:
#       - Label:
#           default: 'HostedZone name'
#         Parameters:
#           - HostedZoneName
Parameters:
  HostedZoneName:
    Description: "The DNS name of an existing Amazon Route 53 hosted zone"
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{1,63}(?<!-)"
    Default: "thecloudcrew.net"


Resources:

  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: !Ref HostedZoneName
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
        ErrorDocument: error.html
      LoggingConfiguration:
        DestinationBucketName: !Ref S3LoggingBucket
        LogFilePrefix: logs

  WWWS3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub
        -  www.${domain}
        - { domain: !Ref HostedZoneName}
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        RedirectAllRequestsTo:
          HostName: !Ref HostedZoneName

  S3LoggingBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub
        - ${domain}.logs
        - { domain: !Ref HostedZoneName}
      AccessControl: LogDeliveryWrite

  HostedZone:
    Type: "AWS::Route53::HostedZone"
    Properties:
      HostedZoneConfig:
        Comment: "My Hosted zone for thecloudcrew.net"
      HostedZoneTags:
        -
          Key: Name
          Value: thecloudcrew
      Name: !Ref HostedZoneName

  RecordSet: #FIXME
    Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSet"
    Properties:
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
        HostedZoneId: Z2O1EMRO9K5GLX
      Comment: "RecordSet for static website"
      HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZone  #TODO
      Name: !Ref HostedZone
      Type: A
      #Region: 'us-east-2'
      # SetIdentifier: String
      # TTL: String
      # Weight: Integer
```

Comment: Does it give you more information when you click on the error to expand it?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `Type: A` property, you have to replace `HosteZoneName` by `HostedZoneId`. Also, remove `Region` it has no use in Route53 which is global.

Comment: I have made the changes, still getting an error  "RRSet with DNS name z3b9u6qmuquywf. is not permitted in zone thecloudcrew.net."

Comment: @MrD I was having issues with route53 in Cloudformation. I used python boto3 instead. Hope it helps